# Fetch model and clear attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How would I get a model and then clear its attributes all at once, so that all of its attributes become `null`?

Is there a method for this?

For example:

```
$model = Model::findOrFail(1);
$model->clearAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

```
public $protected_schema = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function clearAttributes()
{
    foreach (Schema::getColumnListing($this->getTable()) as $name) {
        if (!in_array($name, $this->protected_schema)) {
            $this->{$name} = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Meh.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$model = Model::findOrFail(1);
$model->fill(array_fill_keys($model->getFillable(), null));
```

[`getFillable()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getFillable) will give you a list of fillable properties and [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) will create an array with those keys and `null` as a value.

If you want to save the model to DB after that, just do `$model->save();`